# Python-gitlab Creating a project in a subgroup

Tags: python, gitlab, python-gitlab

My namespace structure is something like `https://gitlab.com/ES/BSK/Projectx`
I'm trying to create a project under the BSK subgroup like projectx.

Each time I try to create a project using the attribute "namespace_id" : "group_id" it ends creating the project in my user space and not in the group's space. It creates username/project instead of ES/BSK/project.

I use the Following commands:

```
group_id = gl.groups.list(search='group_name')[0].id

project_created = gl.projects.create({'name': 'UDS', 'namedspace_id': group_id})
```

OR

```
project_created = gl.projects.create({'name': 'UDS', 'namedspace_id': 78})
```

where 78 is the id for the group

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an unfortunate typo:
It should be `namespace_id`, not `namedspace_id`.

With the wrong spelling, the entry is presumably ignored and the default value used instead (according to the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#create-project), the default is the current user's namespace).